# What ADC precision and sampling rate for record sound?

Tags: analog-to-digital, real-time, embedded-systems

What ADC precision and sampling rate would you choose and why if You wish to record sound that has frequency components are 200 to 2000 Hz. And the signal-to-noise ratio of your microphone is 50 dB?

Comment: Hello sara and welcome to DSP SE. Your question provides very limited information for people to be able to answer. I suggest you provide additional info on your target application, possibly some more info on the hardware you use and the purpose of your application. Additionally, I don't think that "Computer Vision" is an appropriate tag for this question so I suggest you delete it.

Comment: It this a homework question ?

Answer (score 1):

@sara Based on the information you provided, I would suggest a 10-bit A/D converter (ADC) operating at a sample rate of 8000 samples/second.